# Complex inner product linearity

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$. Is the expression

$$
\newcommand{\<}{\langle}
\newcommand{\>}{\rangle} 
\<v,\lambda u\> = \bar{\lambda}\<v,u\> = \bar{\lambda}\overline{\<u,v\>} = \overline{\<\bar{\lambda}u,v\>} = \<v,\bar{\lambda}u\>
$$
true? I mean is every move "legal"?

Answer (score 3):

No, because this isn't justified:

$$\bar{\lambda}\overline{\<u,v\>} = \overline{\<\bar{\lambda}u,v\>} $$

It should be

$$\bar{\lambda}\overline{\<u,v\>} =\overline{\lambda \<u,v\>} = \overline{\<\lambda u,v\>} $$

Comment: It's interesting that you're able to use the custom command from the question body in your answer. Is that just how MathJax works?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Heh, I didn't even notice. Must be!

Answer (score 2):

No, the third equality does not hold. Note that

$$\overline{\lambda}\,\overline{\langle u, v\rangle} = \overline{\lambda\langle u, v\rangle} = \overline{\langle\lambda u, v\rangle}.$$